# Applescript not accepting arRsync sdef commands?

Tags: cocoa, applescript, rsync, sdef

I'm using the opensource GUI frontend for rsync called "arRsync". It works great, but there's no way to automate it.

What I'm trying to do is use Applescript to run a preset (which you define in the Application) using the following simple script:

`tell application "arRsync" to runPreset "presetTest1"`

The problem is Applescript thinks "runPreset" is a variable, not a command. I've also tried a tell/end-tell variation of the above, no dice. The 'runPreset' command is part of arRsync.sdef

You can find the arRsync project [here](http://arrsync.sourceforge.net/)

I've tried opening up both Info.plist files inside the app and ticking the 'Scriptable' box (or setting it to 'true' for those of you without Property List Editor) but I'm still stuck.

I'm a scripting noob when it comes to Cocoa :p help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arRsync binary is missing a scripting dictionary. Build from source, first making the following changes:

1. Edit Info.plist in the project, setting the "Scriptable" option to true.
2. Fix the project's script dictionary, arRsync.sdef. The code for the `runPreset` command has one letter too few ([command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_creating_sdef/SAppsCreateSdef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001977-1129132) codes must be two FourCCs, or eight characters, long). Add a character to `runPreset`'s code attribute; just about any character will work. If you want, the file can be shortened and simplified by replacing the Standard and Text suites with an include. Back up the orignal file and make a new arRsync.sdef containing:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
   <dictionary title="arRsync Terminology"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude">
     <xi:include href="file:///System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef" 
                 xpointer="xpointer(/dictionary/suite)"/>
     <suite name="arRsync Suite" code="arRs">
         <command name="runPreset" code="runPPrst">
             <cocoa name="runPreset" class="scriptController"/>
             <direct-parameter type="any"/>
         </command>
     </suite>
   </dictionary>
   ```

   Alternatively, you could just replace the `runPreset` command element with the one from above.
3. [Add](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/200-Build_Phases/bs_build_phases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002690-CJAFCFEG) arRsync.sdef to the "Copy Bundle Resources" [phase](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/200-Build_Phases/bs_build_phases.html) of the arRsync target
4. [Switch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/210-Building_Products/building.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002693-SW5) to a Release [build](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/400-Build_Configurations/build_configs.html) ("Blackbeard" is the name for the debug build).
5. Build it.

That should produce a scriptable version of arRsync. As you've already figured out, you also might need to play with the target SDK.

Comment: Ok just tried that, it saves as 'Blackbeard.app' instead of 'arRsync.app', but contents looks exactly the same. I tried compiling with and without editing the info.plist file to enable scripting, same problem still exists. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: I'll take a look at the source.

Comment: thank ye very muchly! Oh, just fyi, it doesn't compile on 10.6, gotta use 10.5.

Comment: Are you referring to the undefined `_sleep$UNIX2003` symbol error? I had to target 10.4 and switch to GCC 4.0, myself.